# How to convert multiple dataframes in one CSV to one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do the following in Python, the data is coming from multiple CSVs, one for each week:

The data is in the following form:

```
date         | 
product_code | product_name | sale_amount | sale_qty
```

As you've probably guessed, it is transactional data and I need to pull the date down and fill in a column called date with it.

That's not all though. The file consists of 5 dates (one for each working day of the week) and I need to put them all together in one list. The rest of the file looks like this:

```
date1        |              |             |         | date2        |              |             |
product_code | product_name | sale_amount | sale_qty| product_code | product_name | sale_amount | sale_qty
```

The final result should look like this:

```
date1 | product_code | product_name | sale_amount | sale_qty
date2 | product_code | product_name | sale_amount | sale_qty
...
```

Appreciate any help or pointers!

Comment: Can your update your post with a csv file (plain and raw) please?

Comment: Hi, how do I add a CSV directly here? I've added it to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/2nxQrb4x

Comment: Your csv files are really ugly!!! :-) There is only 3 dates in the file instead of 5, it's normal?

Comment: Yes I only added 3 dates with one date being in the future and therefore no data for that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below (comments inside):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def read_transactional_data(csvfile):
    """Read transactional data file."""
    with open(csvfile) as fp:
        # Extract date from the first line of file
        dti = pd.to_datetime(re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', fp.readline()))

        # Read csv as usual but skip the next two rows
        df = pd.read_csv(fp, sep=',', header=None, skiprows=2)

        # Remove date separator columns (every 5 columns)
        df = df.drop(columns=list(range(4, len(df.columns), 5)))

        # Replace column index by a multi-index (date, variable)
        cols = ['product_code', 'product_name', 'sale_amount', 'sale_qty']
        df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dti, cols], names=['date', None])

        # Make a proper indexed dataframe
        df = df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True) \
               .sort_index().reset_index()
        return df


# From your pastebin file
df = read_transactional_file('data.csv')
```

```
>>> df
        date product_code product_name  sale_amount  sale_qty
0 2021-08-01         P001     Product1        200.0       2.0
1 2021-08-01         P002     Product2        300.0       5.0
2 2021-08-01         P001     Product1        400.0       4.0
3 2021-08-02         P001     Product1        200.0       2.0
4 2021-08-02         P003     Product3        500.0      10.0
5 2021-08-02         P003     Product3        550.0      11.0
6 2021-08-02         P002     Product2        300.0       5.0
```